# Autolink phone numbers

Tags: android, phone-number, autolink

I am using autolink="phone", but however, I have tried to link it with 3 digits (for e.g. 911, for emergency calls), but it doesn't work. Is there a minimum amount of digit before it can link to the dialer? Or is there any quick alternative out there that I can link the emergency number to the dialer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~plaxx/tomdroid/main/revision/167#src/org/tomdroid/util/LinkifyPhone.java) link kind of answers another question, but might solve your problem. Check out "LinkifyPhone". Make a special note of the `PHONE_NUMBER_MINIMUM_DIGITS = 5` variable.

Another, more direct, solution would be to set autolink to "all", and then have some own regex-method.